# Serverless - AWS Lamda with MongoDB Atlas Queries Not Running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, mongodb-atlas

I've created an AWS account and want to use MongoDB Atlas with AWS Lambda.
The only dependency I've downloaded is mongodb locally.

```
npm install mongodb
```

**Driver based** connection string given from mongoDB Atlas for Nodejs is

```
var uri = "mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/test";
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
   const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
   // perform actions on the collection object
   client.close();
});
```

I think the connection is successful, because err parameter is NULL.

But I cannot figure out how to create collection, how to find results, how to insert documents.

I've tried this code

```
module.exports.hello = (event, context, callback) => {

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var uri = "mongodb+srv://kay:myRealPassword@cluster0.mongodb.net/test";
MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
   const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
   collection.insert( { "msg" : "My First Document" } );
   var results = client.db("test").collection("devices").find();
   console.log(results);
   client.close();
   callback(null, { message: 'Go Serverless v1.0! Your function executed successfully!', event });
});

};
```

but it returns (in Windows console) a huge Object in JSON format, its like a configuration data (not a query result)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpmsn.png)

I'm executing this code locally by

```
sls invoke local --function hello
```

Comment: The first thing you need to do is check is the connection was succesfull, and then you can create collections, documents, ... Do you know how to check the connection??

Comment: err parameter in MongoClient.connect is JSON Object , when I entered wrong password/username.
And it returns Null , when username/password is correct

Comment: Let me post an example script that would help you, at least at finding the place where you have the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general idea is to check if there is an error in the connection, the insert, and so on. Take at look at this error checking:

```
if (error) return 1;
```

There are more sophisticated methods, but for your case this should do the work.

This is a example of how it show look your script:

```
MongoClient.connect(uri, (error, client) => {
  if (error) return 1;    // Checking the connection
  console.log('Connection Successful');
  var db = client.db('mydb');        // Your DB

  let newDocument = { "msg" : "My First Document" };    // Your document

  db.collection('mycollection').insert(newDocument, (error, results) => {   // Your collection
    if (error) return 1;   // Checking the insert
    console.log('Insert Successful');
  })

  db.collection('mycollection')
    .find({})
    .toArray((error, accounts) => {
      if (error) return 1;   // Checking the find
      console.log('Find Successful');
      console.log(accounts);
      return 0;
  })

})
```

And you should have an output like this:

```
Connection Successful
Insert Successful
Find Successful
[ { _id: 5a857dd2c940040d85cbe5f2, msg: 'My First Document' } ]
```

If your output is not like this, well the missing log would point the place where you have your error.

Comment: Thank You for you answer!
Your code worked as expected.
I've one confusion , i cannot find mistake in my code.

Comment: Try adding logging in key points in your script, and I'm not sure about `const collection`, try with `var`. Or you can add the JSON object to your question, so maybe we can see what is happening.

Comment: I've edited my post , this is an image of console.log(results) 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpmsn.png
can you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Is better if you post your errors in text, not add an image.